# Geocoder limitations

Tags: android, geocoding

I am building an android application, and i am using Geocoder to decode the location, but i have noticed that sometimes when there is comparatively low connectivity Gecoder does not work. But during the same time, the browser and the rest of the internet based apps function. Is there any way to fix this ? What could possibly be going wrong in this. I do understand that its a back end service but it should not matter.For regular http requests we could give a retry and fix similar issues, but how can i fix this ? Any suggestions?

```
class ReverseGeocodingTask extends AsyncTask<Double, Void, String> implements OnDismissListener{

    Context context;
    ProgressDialog progDialog;
    String progressString;

    public ReverseGeocodingTask(Context context, String progressStr) {
        this.context = context;
        this.progressString = progressStr;
        if(!isCancelled()){
            initProgDialog();
        }

    }

    void initProgDialog(){

        progDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        progDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        progDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, getString(R.string.btn_cancel),new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, final int id) {
                progDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        progDialog.setMessage(progressString);
        progDialog.setOnDismissListener(this);
        progDialog.show();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        //removeAllPendingRevGeocodingTasks();
        addTask(this);
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Double... params) {
        String result = null;

        if(!isCancelled()){
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());  
            try {
                List<Address> list = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);

                if (list != null && list.size() > 0) {
                    Address address = list.get(0);
                    result = address.getAddressLine(0) + ", " + address.getLocality();
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                progDialog.dismiss();
                failedToUpdateLocation();
                Log.e("Location listener", "Failed to decode location name");
            }
        }
        return result;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        progDialog.dismiss();
        this.cancel(true);
        super.onCancelled();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        latLongInDegrees = " "+latLongInDegreesToDMSString(latitude,longitude);
        setLocationName(result);
        updateLocationName(result + latLongInDegrees);

        String progressStr=getString(R.string.msg_slp_fetch_from_geocoder_result_1)+latLongInDegreesToDMSString(latitude,longitude)+"...";
        executeSLPWebserviceTask(latitude, longitude, progressStr);
        finishedUpdatingLocation(latitude,longitude);
        progDialog.dismiss();
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        this.cancel(true);
        //removeAllPendingRevGeocodingTasks();
    }

    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
        this.cancel(true);
    }

}


protected void executeRevGeocoderTask(double lat, double longitude)
{
    String progressStr=getString(R.string.msg_rev_geocoder_fetch)+" "+latLongInDegreesToDMSString(lat,longitude);
    ReverseGeocodingTask task = new ReverseGeocodingTask(this,progressStr);
    task.execute(lat,longitude);
}
```

Comment: Yes sometimes Geocoder fails. Can you please post your code?

Comment: I have posted my code, Btw.. by any chance, is Geocoder using the google services that is there in android ?

Comment: I think yes. And i read somewhere that in Geocoder of Google you can send 1 request/15 seconds from a IP...

Comment: Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault()); 

here i think you need to pass YourActivityclassname.this.getApplicationContext(). I have also use Async Task in my previous app and its working fine. So try this once, may be it will resolve the problem.

Comment: YourActivityclassname.this.getApplicationContext() how is this different from getApplicationContext(), if there is something wrong in the context then my implmentation should never work. But my problem is that sometimes it does not work in low connectivity. else it works just fine..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Geocoder is a backend service for which we dont have any handle on its http request or anything of that sort. it requires good internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes Geocoder needs a rebooting of the device to get working. It happens on Android 4: I don't know how to fix this.